# Notifications didn't work for me in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I try to build a notification system, in which anyone (user) clicks like in the video then send a notification, and after this didn't work for me I don't know why

my notification model

```py
class Notification(models.Model):
    NOTIFICATION_TYPE = ((1, 'like'))

    video = models.ForeignKey("videos.Video", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_video", blank=True, null=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_from_user")
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_to_user")
    notification_type = models.IntegerField(choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPE)
    text_preview = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

the notification in the video model

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='post-videos', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True, related_name='likes', default=None)



    # # get the like notifications
      def user_liked_video(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance.likes
        video = like
        sender = like.account
        notify = Notification(video=video, sender=sender, user=video.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.save()

    def user_unliked_video(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance
        video = object.self
        sender = object.self.author
        notify = Notification(video=video, sender=sender, user=video.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.delete()
```

the view of the notification

```py
def showNotifications(request):
    user = request.user
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date')
    template = loader.get_template('notifications/notifications.html')
    context = {
        'notifications': notifications,
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: Did you have an error?

Comment: I don't have an error but there's not anything that happened when I try to add like from the different user

Comment: Where is the view that is called when you like a video

Comment: did you mean the like view?

Comment: Yes, it's probably where the problem is.